# Callback methods do not work for Hibernate beans

Tags: java, hibernate, callback, listener

I do everything according to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html, but neither in-bean methods nor external ones are ever executed. What might be the cause?

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(EntityListener.class)
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    // etc...

    @PostConstruct
    @PostLoad
    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate    
    public void magic() {
        System.out.println("YES I AM EXECUTED!");
        System.exit(123);
    }
}
```

OR

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyListener.class)
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    // etc...       
}
```

+

```
public class MyListener {
    @PostPersist
    void postPersist(Object object) {
        System.out.println("CAN'T BELEIVE I SEE THIS!");
        System.exit(234);
    }
}
```

My code creates, saves and loads beans, but nothing happens on the listeners. This is a piece of the repository thats perform the operations:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public User get(Integer id) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        user = (User) session.merge(user);
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);

        return user;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Repository methods are called from services like this one:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void something() {
        // just some repo calls + extra logic
    }
}
```

I do not think I got something special here.

Comment: Do you can show how you save and load entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA interceptors mechanism work only when you manipulate entities via JPA `EntityManager`, they have no effect when you're using Hibernate `Session` directly.

You'll have to implement [Hibernate native interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html) if you want to use the `Session` API.

Comment: Does not look very elegant, and that is why I tried to avoid the approah. But okay... Thank you for the keen and clean answer anyway!